# Control Raspberry Pi with Android app over Wi-Fi

Tags: remote, android

I want to do something like this ([Control car by wifi using Android and Arduino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-oRrcYfv8o)) using Raspberry Pi and Android.

On my Raspberry I already have the program for motors, but I want to make something like a joystick on my phone.

My problem is how to send this data to the Raspberry terminal?